# k8s network policy with helm template

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I've created the following `newtworkPolicy` file (for the first time :) and I've issue with the syntax, the error is for line 14 .

```
templates/network-policy.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: block sequence entries are not allowed in this context


{{- $name := "cvtor-network-policy" }}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: {{$name}}
  namespace: {{.Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      control-plane: cvm
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
    - Egress
  ingress: {{- $ingress := .Values.networkPolicy.ingress }}
           {{- if $ingress.cidr }}
  - from:
      - ipBlock:
          cidr: {{ $ingress.cidr }}
                {{- if $ingress.except }}
        except: {{ toYaml $ingress.except | nindent 12 }}
                {{- end }}
                {{- end }}
            {{- if $ingress.ports }}
  - ports: {{ toYaml $ingress.ports }}
           {{- end }}
  egress:
      {{- $egress := .Values.networkPolicy.egress }}
      {{- if $egress.ports }}
  - ports: {{ toYaml $egress.ports }}
      {{- end }}
```

line 14 is:

```
  ingress: {{- $ingress := .Values.networkPolicy.ingress }}
           {{- if $ingress.cidr }}
    - from:
```

please see the following, any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the actual issue?  Do you have an error message?  If there a specific set of Helm values that causes the problem?

Comment: @DavidMaze - I've update the post with the errors, can you please have a look?

Comment: And to double-check, you're getting these errors out of `helm install` or `helm template`, not `kubectl apply` or some other tool that expects the unprocessed input to be YAML?

Comment: @DavidMaze - im getting the error during the helm install, I've update the post with additional info, could you please have a loo?

Comment: You might try running `helm template --debug` with your set of values.  That should print out a similar YAML error, but also the actual text of what it's trying to parse; sometimes it's obvious where an extra newline has gotten swallowed or where the indentation is wrong.

Comment: @DavidMaze - thank you, I tried helm template debug and I got all the yaml's outputs, however for the network policy I got the same error: `templates/network-policy.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 14: block sequence entries are not allowed in this context
` I think its related to my networkPolicy yaml syntax, does it looks right to you?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer with an [mcve]: sufficient information that we could run `helm template` to reproduce the problem. Maybe you could reduce the number of template values and then provide a sample `values.yaml`? The output of `helm template --debug` should have shown you the output of your template; if it did, can you post that?